# An ideal I subscript d

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

Let $K$ be a field.
If $I \subset K[x_1,...,x_n]$ is an ideal what do we mean by the notation $I_d$ for some integer $d$? I can not find and reference anywhere to a definition. My intuition tells me that $I_d$ is the ideal generated by all the generators of $I$ with degree $d$ but I don't know for sure if this is correct.

Comment: Possible meanings: (1) The ideal generated by the elements of $I$ of degree $d$.  (2) The set of elements of degree $d$ (as a graded ring) (3) A twist by $d$ (but that would be very nonstandard notation).

Comment: Is $I$ homogeneous?

Comment: Yes I is a homogeneous ideal

Comment: Then your intuition is correct.